# watchOS 10 CMBatchedSensorManager, crashes on startDeviceMotionUpdates / startAccelerometerUpdates

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, watchos, sensormanager

I've been waiting to try these APIs. I had already tried them on Beta with no luck and thought on release I would be able to use them. Today I tried with xCode 15 and any calls to start something from the CMBatchedSensorManager will result in a crash after a few seconds on the thread:

Thread 7 Queue : com.apple.tcc.kTCCServiceMotion (serial)

No error message, just crash.

Am I doing something wrong?

Update:

I had read somewhere that HealthKit is required but then forgotten about it. However, I tried now with adding capabilities to both my iOS and watchOS project. I still don't get it working.

I call HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() and can see it's available on both my devices. I create let healthStore = HKHealthStore() in my App class even though I don't use it.
Then when I call

```
private let batchedMotion = CMBatchedSensorManager()

func startBatchUpdate() {
    print("starting")
    batchedMotion.startDeviceMotionUpdates { (x, e) in
        print("started")
        print(x)
    }
```

It takes a while and then crashes.

[image]

Update 2:
I was finally able to call the apis without getting a crash by adding
Privacy - Motion Usage Description in info.plist.
It would be really nice if I had an error message, I just guessed this this time.

However, I get no data and I get an Error. The block parameters x: [CMDeviceMotion]?,
e: Error? gives me nil on the x and for the error I get:

"The operation couldn’t be completed. (CMErrorDomain error 109.)"

Comment: Hard to tell what you are doing wrong without seeing your code. Please [edit] your question and include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I'm just hoping someone tells me that they've gotten data from CMBatchedSensorManager at this point. Just so that I know the APIs are working and I'm doing something wrong. Have you done that?

Comment: I'm new to swift and would like to try out out the new APIs. Would you mind posting a minimal ContentView file that initializes the CMBachedSensorManager? Or can anyone show their code? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a workout centric API, this means that you need an active HealthKit workout session. Do you have one active when trying to get the batched sensor data?

Comment: Thanks. You are right, I had forgotten about this. But still, I can't manage to get it working. I've updated the question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

You need

1 - Privacy - Motion Usage Description in info.plist

2 - HealthKit and active workout session